# MySql Get SUM of one field for every id from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my Sql tables:

[image]

I need to do a SUM of the field "Fatturato" for every "IdProdotto" that are connected to "CodiceMercato".

I also tryed this code

```
SELECT prodotti.Fatturato, immettere.CodiceMercato
FROM prodotti INNER JOIN immettere ON immettere.CodiceImmissioni = prodotti.IdProdotto
INNER JOIN (
SELECT SUM(prodotti.Fatturato)
FROM prodotti);
```

I don't know how to connect the tables, can someone please help me?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the table "immettere" has the foreign key that is the primary key of mercati and the primary key of prodotti. In the image I didn't add those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your relational drawning, looks like is missing the field `idProdotto` on `immettere` table.

But, following the fields in your query example, we can do this:

```sql
SELECT i.CodiceMercato, p.IdProdotto, SUM(p.Fatturato) AS Fatturato
FROM prodotti p
INNER JOIN immettere i ON i.IdProdotto = p.IdProdotto
GROUP BY p.IdProdotto, i.CodiceMercato
```

Comment: Ok thank's, I try it but I didn't see nothing, I need to see the SUM of Fatturato. It only print me the name of the fields

Comment: This is probrably because there is no relation rows between these two tables/fields `immettere.CodiceImmissioni` and `prodotti.IdProdotto`. These relational fields are correct?

Comment: This is the structure of mysql

immettere --- https://prnt.sc/13k46di
mercati --- https://prnt.sc/13k495l
prodotti --- https://prnt.sc/13k4a2c

Comment: Ok, fixed the relation with `INNER JOIN immettere i ON i.IdProdotto = p.IdProdotto`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're looking for below -

```
SELECT prodotti.IdProdotto, SUM(prodotti.Fatturato)
FROM prodotti 
INNER JOIN immettere ON immettere.IdProdotto = prodotti.IdProdotto
INNER JOIN mercati ON immettere.CodiceMercato = mercati.CodiceMercato
group by prodotti.IdProdotto ;
```

HTH !